# Serializing arrays result wrong JSON

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, jil

I recently realized that serializing arrays with both **Json.NET** and **Jil** libraries, results a wrong JSON object! at least as far as https://jsonlint.com says. For example

```
var serializer = // Json.NET_Serializer or Jil_Serializer;
var json = serializer.Serialize(new[] {1,2,3,4,5});
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

results `{ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }` which as https://jsonlint.com (and also https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) says, is wrong

> // The error message in jsonformatter:
>
> Expecting string or }, not [.

and expected result I think is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Is there any hidden point which I missed? For example is there any special setting in Json.NET or Jil to solve this problem?

**UPDATE:** Note that the question is not how to achieve the mentioned result. But is about how to get **JSON.NET** or **JIL** to work right. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you printing out your JSON?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen writing in console, or setting breakpoint, or saving in database...

Comment: Have you tried adding your array object into a variable 1st?

Comment: @AnestisKivranoglou yes. In my project, it's assigned to a variable. But I cannot understand how it can make any difference at all?

Answer (score 1):

No idea what you're doing wrong, but with the following code using JSON.Net:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new[] {1,2,3,4,5});

        Console.WriteLine(json);

        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, new[] {1,2,3,4,5});

            Console.WriteLine(sw);
        }
    }
}
```

I get the correct output with both `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` and `JsonSerializer.Serialize()` (fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mFxvrf)):

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using JavScriptSerializer, like so -

```
new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new[] {1,2,3,4,5});
```

That produces the expected result for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using `JArray.FromObject()` works fine for me:

```
Console.WriteLine(JArray.FromObject(new[] {1,2,3,4,5}));
```